# Автоматические сообщения от чатбота телеграмм пользователям

Tags: python, бот, чат

Как можно настроить автопостинг телеграмм бота?

Например, я хочу, чтобы всем пользователям бот написал 31 декабря в 15:00 сообщение "С наступающим новым годом, друзья!".

Пока не представляю даже, как это реализовать и какие есть работающие методы.

Пока пытаюсь собирать айдишники людей, которые обращаются к боту, следующим образом:

```
joinedFile = open ("C:/admin.txt", 'r')
joinedUsers = set()
for line in joinedFile:
    joinedUsers.add(line.strip())
joinedFile.close()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def startJoin(message):
    if not str(message.chat.id) in joinedUsers:
        joinedFile = open("C:/admin.txt", 'a')
        joinedFile.write(str(message.chat.id)) + '\n'
        joinedUsers.add(message.chat.id)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['special'])
def mess(message):
    for user in joinedUsers:
        bot.send_message(user, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])
```

Что-то делаю не так: бот не отправляет сообщения

```
import datetime
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler()
def mess(message):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    if today.year == 2020 and today.month == 8 and today.day == 27:
        bot.send_message(*здесь id конкретного человека*, "С наступающим новым годом, друзья!")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

и вот так тоже

```
def send_message():
    bot.send_message(*здесь id конкретного человека*, 'Hello')
    schedule.every().Thursday.at("20:55").do(send_message())
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Последняя правка:

```
import datetime
import telebot
import schedule
import time

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')
joinedFile = open('C:/Users/joined.txt', 'r')
joinedUser = set()
for line in joinedFile:
    joinedUser.add(line.strip())
joinedFile.close()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
  if not str(message.chat.id) in joinedUser:
    file = open('C:/Users/joined.txt', 'a')
    file.write(str(message.chat.id) + '\n')
    file.close()
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ' + str(message.from_user.first_name) + '!')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAIFPl9Et_P93IpHwPWv0IH_T1ovdN74AAJ0AQACz7vUDvujftMdDnk4GwQ')
def new_year_greetings(joinedUser):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    if today.month == 8 and today.day == 28:
        for user in joinedUser:
            bot.send_message(user, "С наступающим новым годом, друзья!")


def notifications(joinedUser):
    """Каждый день проверяем в 00:01 не новый ли год наступает"""
    schedule.every().day.at('00:01').do(new_year_greetings, joinedUser)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1) # можно значительно увеличить это значение (сейчас интервал 1 секунда)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    notifications(joinedUser)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
import datetime

@bot.message_handler()
def mess(message):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    if today.month == 12 and today.day == 31:
        for user in joinedUsers:
            bot.send_message(user, "С наступающим новым годом, друзья!")
```

---

**UPDATE.** Вот только что проверил полностью работает:

```
import datetime
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def mess(message):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    if today.year == 2020 and today.month == 8 and today.day == 27:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "С наступающим новым годом, друзья!")


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

---

**UPDATE 2**. Просто добавьте это отдельной функцией которая будет выполняться при соответствии условий и запустите в отдельном потоке:

```
import datetime
import telebot
import schedule
import time
import threading


bot = telebot.TeleBot('ваш токен')
joinedFile = open('joined.txt', 'r')
joinedUser = set()
for line in joinedFile:
    joinedUser.add(line.strip())
joinedFile.close()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    if not str(message.chat.id) in joinedUser:
        file = open('joined.txt', 'a+') 
        file.write(str(message.chat.id) + '\n')
        file.close()


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}  !')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAIFPl9Et_P93IpHwPWv0IH_T1ovdN74AAJ0AQACz7vUDvujftMdDnk4GwQ')


def new_year_greetings(joinedUser):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    if today.month == 8 and today.day == 28:
        for user in joinedUser:
            bot.send_message(user, "С наступающим новым годом, друзья!")


def notifications(joinedUser):
    """Каждый день проверяем в 00:01 не новый ли год наступает"""
    schedule.every().day.at('00:59').do(new_year_greetings, joinedUser)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)  # можно значительно увеличить это значение (сейчас интервал 1 секунда)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=bot.polling)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=notifications, args=(joinedUser,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я, вероятно, что-то делаю не так... но бот не отправляет сообщения

Comment: да, работает после того как обратиться к нему с командой /start. У меня просто кривая формулировка вопроса: подразумевается, что айдишники всех, кто уже обращался с этой командой, собраны, и бот БЕЗ всяких команд сам по себе в определенное время должен устроить им рассылку

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, посмотреть: что я делаю не так?

Comment: Смотрите ответ последнее обновление - у меня работает

Comment: огромное спасибо, всё получилось! неуклонного роста репутации вам!))))