# Запланиронные сообщения от телеграм бота по заданной дате

Tags: python, telebot

Хочу, чтобы в нужный мне день в нужное время бот сам отправлял пользователю сообщение с какой-либо информацией.
Сейчас получается так, что он отправляет сообщение, только если к нему обратиться и пользователь нажал /start .
Как я могу сделать, чтобы бот САМ в нужную дату и время отправлял сообщение?

```
import datetime
import telebot
import time
import schedule

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')


@bot.message_handler()
def mess(message):
    if datetime.date(2020, 8, 27) and datetime.time(21, 38, 00):
        bot.send_message(*userid*, "Привет!")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Сообщение запланировано только тем пользователям, которые уже отправляли "старт" и бот получил их айдишники.

Нужно, чтобы бот САМ без активности пользователей отправлял им рассылку по собранным уже ранее айдишникам

Comment: Если пользователь не нажал/написал боту `/start`, то бот не может с ним взаимодейвствовать

Comment: Сообщение запланировано только тем пользователям, которые уже отправляли "старт" и бот получил их айдишники...

Comment: А идентификаторы пользователей у вас где-то отдельно хранятся?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автоматические сообщения от чатбота телеграмм пользователям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1171310/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc)

Comment: да, хранятся в текстовом файле в рабочей директории. Пока пробую  с конкретным айдишником, чтоб хоть как-то сработало